# Аналог функций LeftStr и RightStr Паскаля в Си

Tags: c, pascal, c++

Здравствуйте!

Мне нужно переписать на си программу на паскале. В ней используются функции:

```
function LeftStr(s: string; count: integer): string; 
        Возвращает первые count символов строки s

function RightStr(s: string; count: integer): string; 
        Возвращает последние count символов строки s
```

Прошу помочь найти их аналоги в Си.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать как-нибудь так

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))

char *left_str(const char *src, size_t len){
    return strndup(src, len);
}

char *right_str(const char *src, size_t len)
{
    size_t str_len=strlen(src);
    len=MIN(len, str_len);
    char *dst=(char*)malloc(len+1);
    strcpy(dst, src+str_len-len);
    return dst;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", left_str("12345", 2));
    printf("%s %s\n", right_str("12345", 2), right_str("12345", 8));
}
```

Comment: Или в том же духе, что и left\_str()


    char *right_str (const char *str, int len) {
      int pos = strlen(str) - len;
      return strdup(str + (pos > 0 ? pos : 0));
    }

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

В Си если память под эти символы уже выделена, то используйте strncpy + сами запишете завершающий 0 (можете написать и назвать ее strncpyz()) и strcpy (естественно).

(strcpy для копирования "хвоста" используйте, конечно, так -- strcpy(your_result_mem, s + count);)

Если хотите получить в динамической памяти, то strndup и strdup вполне сгодятся.